# How to do testing with lift applications?

Tags: testing, scala, lift

How to do testing and is there something similar like Rack::Test with ruby frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Specs, ScalaTest and JUnit (and any other java test framework), theres some examples on the new wiki.

[Read this!](http://wiki.github.com/dpp/liftweb/how-to-unit-test-lift-snippets-with-a-logged-in-user)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about ruby, so maybe don't get your point. But what about [Jitr](http://www.jitr.org)?

> Jitr (pronounced "jitter") is a JUnit
>   Integration Test Runner.
>   It allows your web application
>   integration tests to easily run
>   against a lightweight web container in
>   the same JVM as your tests.

You can use it with JUnit 4's `@RunWith` annotation. In Scala: `@RunWith(classOf[Jitr])`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help, it's on Lifts wiki pages. There are examples using Junit, Scalatest and and Specs.

[How To: Unit test lift snippets with a logged in user](http://wiki.github.com/dpp/liftweb/how-to-unit-test-lift-snippets-with-a-logged-in-user)